# Doubt in a example on Taylor's series

Tags: calculus

[[image: here is the totally different story ... Here <span class=]$h$ is taken 1 (improper fraction) and $x$ is 25(very big)">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbYEL.jpg)[image]

I learned how to use taylor's series and practised few questions like $sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})$ etc.

But in this example..

---

Value of $f(\frac{9}{10})$ is asked 
And my **Question** is why $x$ is taken 1 or why $h$ is taken as $\frac{-1}{10}$

**OR** why $\frac{9}{10}$ Is splitted in such a particular way...

Comment: No pictures please, typeset the equations.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Taylor series makes sense to be used when $h$ is small, and then its powers get very small very fast, allowing to add only a few terms. If you expand at $0$ and take $h=9/10$, then you need $h^{21}$ to get it less than $0.1$; that is, in general (specifics would depend on the series), you may need up to 20 terms to just get a precision of one decimal.

Expanding around $1$ and using a much smaller $h$ makes the series converge a lot faster, as the example shows.

Comment: It means we always have to take $x=1$ in such questons

Comment: Or our focus should be on $h$ to have it as a proper fraction

Comment: You need to expand around a point where the derivatives are easy. Other than that, you go for the smallest $h$ you can get.

Comment: Kindly look at my new edit..

Comment: Okay..i got it. Thank you